# Datatable requested unknown parameter '2' from data source row 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

Hello I'm having issues trying to show data from my DB, I can show each data from the table in my DB but when I try to show all in a table it gives the error in the title, I don't know why. I'm using codeigniter.

This is the controller function

```
public function datatable()
{

    $this->datatables->select('name', 'user_id', 'last_name','identify','contact','rol_type')       
        ->unset_column('user_id')
        ->add_column('actions', get_buttons('$1','users'),'user_id')
        ->from('users')
        ->where(array('user_status'=>'1'));

    echo $this->datatables->generate();

}
```

User_id is an autoincrement variable.

This is the view page.

```
<?php
//set table id in table open tag
    $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="mytable">' );
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 

    $this->table->set_heading('Name','Last Name','Identify Card','Contact Number','Rol assign,'Actions');
    echo $this->table->generate();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {            

    var oTable = $('#big_table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/datatable',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayStart ":20,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sUrl":'<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/translate'
        },
                "fnInitComplete": function() {
                //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    },
                'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
                    {
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                          'dataType': 'json',
                          'type'    : 'POST',
                          'url'     : sSource,
                          'data'    : aoData,
                          'success' : fnCallback
                        });
                    }
    } );

} );

</script>
```

I use the datatable code for other functions on my program and it works, and even showing more than 4 data selected.

The data I'm showing it has integer, and strings.

Datatable version is 0.7

Comment: Which codeigniter library for datatables you use? Tell us, it may help debug your problem.

Comment: The version of datatables is 0.7

Comment: datatables 0.7 or codeigniter datatables 0.7?

Comment: Codeigniter Datatables version 0.7

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding,  I've asked about library that uses `    echo $this->datatables->generate();` I could'nt trace any library with 0.7 version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public function works like this

```
public function datatable()
{
    //$this->datatables->select('name', 'user_id', 'last_name','identify','contact','rol_type')
    $this->datatables->select('name')
        ->select('last_name')
        ->select('identify')
        ->select('contact')
        ->select('rol_type')
        //->unset_column('user_id')
        ->add_column('Actions', get_buttons('$1','users'),'user_id')  
        ->from('users')
        ->where(array('user_status'=>'1'));

    echo $this->datatables->generate();

}
```

I don't know why Select must be like this instead of the comented one. But it fixs the table and show it properly.